# Line In Headset's Microphone Not Receiving Input

Tags: audio, bootcamp, headphones, microphone, recording

I'm using Windows 10 (32 bit) with Boot Camp on an early 2009 iMac.

I recently got an X2 from Ovann (http://ovann.com/c2223.html) and looks like this (http://phongvu.vn/gallery/avatar_upload/products/storage/32083_ovann-x2-proo.jpg)

I've tried this on OS X and on Windows and checked the recording devices; it seems that whenever I talk or test the microphone it doesn't get any input.

Comment: Then check it in OS X & see what happens...

Comment: Plug a known good input into the line in and see if that works. Right now, we don't know if it's the X2 or the line in jack that's problematic.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved it! The only thing I needed to do was find a good line-in to USB adapter and then use it.

The one I got was [this one](http://www.amazon.de/CSL-Externe-Soundkarte-Virtual-Surround/dp/B00C7LXUDY?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s01).

Comment: It's helpful if you provide details about the line-in to USB adapter